# Filtering query by passing idProduct, quantity

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to create an Order_List with different ITEMS from a table called: Products

Inside **table Products** there are  duplicates because a product is sell in different supermarkets, with differents prices.

I want the user to enter the desired product inside **List table** and get the lowest price. DO NOTE that every user has a different zipcode and every product belongs to a different supermarket with a different zipcode. **The idea is to get the lowest price ONLY if the item has the same customer zipcode**.Also, the quantity that was inserted in List table must be validated against Stock table.

This is what i have:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f73a/1

This is my example:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayvYW.jpg)

This is what i tried so far:

```
select p.idProduct, name, price, min(price)
from product p
inner join market m
on p.idMarket = m.idMarket
inner join stock s
on p.idProduct = s.idProduct
inner join list l
on p.idProduct = l.idProduct
where p.idProduct = 14
and exists (select 1 
           from stock s
           where p.idProduct = s.idProduct
           and l.quantity <= s.quantity)
group by p.idProduct, name, price
```

Could you please help me to solve this mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.idProduct, p.name, p.price, min(p.price)
from product p
inner join market m
on p.idMarket = m.idMarket
inner join stock s
on p.idProduct = s.idProduct
inner join list l
on p.idProduct = l.idProduct
where p.idProduct = 14
and exists (select 1 
           from stock s1
           where p.idProduct = s1.idProduct
           and l.quantity <= s1.quantity)
and p.price = (select min(price) from product p2 where p2.idProduct = p.idProduct)
group by p.idProduct, p.name, p.price
```

Comment: I am sorry but your fiddle here is the same as in the question. What do you mean by "i put 800 units in List table for productid = 14 and it showed result"

Comment: Sorry, i was confused. How can i obtain the "total price" in List table?

Comment: Does this code answers your question ? In your question there is nothing about the total Price?

Comment: You have to show the people the results you want. Like OP has done here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683205/first-pass-yield-sql-query Do you need this total price : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f73a/11

Comment: Not exactly.. if you look at list tablei i entered 8 units and the price for a single unit is 1 dollar so i want to display 8 in totalprice. Do you get me?

Comment: As I said. Shw the desired results. Here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f73a/13